# How to filter and group products in angularjs in single loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have JSON array like this:

```
[
    {
        "Variants": [],
        "SubCategoryID": "53",
        "ProductImagePath": "/images/quaker/1247.png",
        "SubCategoryName": "Oats",
        "BrandName": "Quaker",
        "ProductID": "1247",
        "BrandID": "229",
        "ProductName": "Oats - Home Style Masala"
    },
    {
        "Variants": [],
        "SubCategoryID": "53",
        "ProductImagePath": "/images/quaker/1247.png",
        "SubCategoryName": "Oats",
        "BrandName": "Suffola",
        "ProductID": "1047",
        "BrandID": "129",
        "ProductName": "Oats - Home Style Masala"
    },
    {
        "Variants": [],
        "SubCategoryID": "53",
        "ProductImagePath": "/images/quaker/1246.png",
        "SubCategoryName": "Oats",
        "BrandName": "Quaker",
        "ProductID": "1246",
        "BrandID": "229",
        "ProductName": "Oats - Kesar Flavour with Kismis"
    },

    {
        "Variants": [],
        "SubCategoryID": "53",
        "ProductImagePath": "/images/quaker/1246.png",
        "SubCategoryName": "Oats",
        "BrandName": "Suffola",
        "ProductID": "1046",
        "BrandID": "129",
        "ProductName": "Oats - Kesar Flavour with Kismis"
    },

    {
        "Variants": [],
        "SubCategoryID": "53",
        "ProductImagePath": "/images/quaker/1245.png",
        "SubCategoryName": "Oats",
        "BrandName": "Quaker",
        "ProductID": "1245",
        "BrandID": "229",
        "ProductName": "Oats - Multigrain Advantage"
    },

    {
        "Variants": [],
        "SubCategoryID": "53",
        "ProductImagePath": "/images/quaker/1245.png",
        "SubCategoryName": "Oats",
        "BrandName": "Suffola",
        "ProductID": "1045",
        "BrandID": "129",
        "ProductName": "Oats - Multigrain Advantage"
    },
    {
        "Variants": [],
        "SubCategoryID": "38",
        "ProductImagePath": "/images/dry_fruits/walnut.jpg",
        "SubCategoryName": "Dry Fruits",
        "BrandName": "Quality Plus",
        "ProductID": "24",
        "BrandID": "58",
        "ProductName": "Chestnut (Akhrot Gota)"
    },
    {
        "Variants": [],
        "SubCategoryID": "38",
        "ProductImagePath": "/images/dry_fruits/walnut.jpg",
        "SubCategoryName": "Dry Fruits",
        "BrandName": "Quality Plus",
        "ProductID": "24",
        "BrandID": "58",
        "ProductName": "Chestnut -2 (Akhrot Gota)"
    },
    {
        "Variants": [],
        "SubCategoryID": "38",
        "ProductImagePath": "/images/dry_fruits/walnut.jpg",
        "SubCategoryName": "Dry Fruits",
        "BrandName": "Quality Plus",
        "ProductID": "24",
        "BrandID": "58",
        "ProductName": "Chestnut -3 (Akhrot Gota)"
    }
]
```

We can display the products of a particular SubCategory using this:

```
<div class='box' ng-repeat="product in pc.ProductService.Products | filter:FilterExpr:true | orderBy:'ProductName'">
    <!-- Code to display the products -->
</div>
```

Where I am setting  FilterExpr in JavaScript on selecting a subcategory:

```
$scope.FilterExpr = {'SubCategoryID': $stateParams.SCID.toString()};
```

For example -  on selecting SubCategoryID = 53, product will be displayed like this:

```
    "BrandName": "Quaker",
    "ProductName": "Oats - Home Style Masala"

    "BrandName": "Suffola",
    "ProductName": "Oats - Home Style Masala"

    "BrandName": "Quaker",
    "ProductName": "Oats - Kesar Flavour with Kismis"

    "BrandName": "Suffola",
    "ProductName": "Oats - Kesar Flavour with Kismis"

    "BrandName": "Quaker",
    "ProductName": "Oats - Multigrain Advantage"

    "BrandName": "Suffola",
    "ProductName": "Oats - Multigrain Advantage"
```

But i want to group them by Brand Name also, means all products of a particular brands in selected subcategory must be display together:

```
    "BrandName": "Quaker",
    "ProductName": "Oats - Home Style Masala"

    "BrandName": "Quaker",
    "ProductName": "Oats - Kesar Flavour with Kismis"

    "BrandName": "Quaker",
    "ProductName": "Oats - Multigrain Advantage"

    "BrandName": "Suffola",
    "ProductName": "Oats - Home Style Masala"

    "BrandName": "Suffola",
    "ProductName": "Oats - Kesar Flavour with Kismis"

    "BrandName": "Suffola",
    "ProductName": "Oats - Multigrain Advantage"
```

How to do that??

Answer (score 1):

Try this with group by

```
<div class='box' ng-repeat="product in pc.ProductService.Products | filter:FilterExpr:true | groupBy:'BrandName' | orderBy:'ProductName'">
    <!-- Code to display the products -->
</div>


app.filter('groupBy', function() {
    return _.memoize(function(items, field) {
            return _.groupBy(items, field);
        }
    );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TD7t3/

Comment: Thanks for quick response. After trying your suggestion i m seeing this error: ReferenceError: _ is not defined, any idea??

Comment: include: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js